# How to change this tuple to another all word tuple?

Tags: python, pyspark, word-count

I have the tuple:

```
wordsTuple = [(('431949',['python',
                          'print',
                          'hellow',
                          'world',
                          'at',
                          'py',
                          'file',
                          ...]
```

I want to change it to `[(python, 1), (print, 1) ...]`. How could I only use one line code or some function from PySpark to achieve this?

```
counts = wordsTuple._________________
```

Comment: Can you please clearly state how your `wordsTuple` looks like? Is it just a `tuple` or `list` of `tuple` ? The description shows a different format while the title shows different

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want a fixed "1" as the second item of each tuple then it's simply

```
wordsTuple = ('431949',['python', 'print', 'hellow', 'world', 'at', 'py', 'file'])
counts = [(x,1) for x in wordsTuple[1]]
counts
[('python', 1), ('print', 1), ('hellow', 1), ('world', 1), ('at', 1), ('py', 1), ('file', 1)]
```

If instead you are looking for the number of occurrences of each world then check the `collections.Counter` class

Comment: From the format of `wordsTuple` added in the question, it does not looks like an list of tuples `[(('431949', [....]), ('', [...]))]`

Comment: Well, since the format is unclear in the question body I took the one in the title (and conversely I trusted the body and not the title for the expected output). In any case I presume that a list containing a tuple containing all the 2-items tuples is not so useful :) Perhaps it was meant to be a list of  tuples and not a single one as I have assumed.